# Entity Framework code first - update database in production

Tags: entity-framework, model, migration

I have enabled migrations. I am not using automatic migrations and I do not want to use them. 
I have done 3 migrations.
In my development environment I am updating database via VS using the command

```
Update-Database -verbose -StartUpProjectName EntityFrameworkContext -TargetMigration <MigrationName>
```

In my devlopment environment, everything works correctly.

Now, I must update the database in production environment. I am using following command

```
Update-Database -verbose -StartUpProjectName EntityFrameworkContext -TargetMigration <MigrationName> -script
```

I run the generated script on production database. No error. The table __MigrationHistory looks to be good (I have just some doubt about the column Model that is different from dev environment). In this tabel I have the correct number of rows and the column MigrationId is correctly filled.

The database is exactly the same of the dev database. I have checked it.

I have updated also the program.

But, I do not understand why I still have always the same error:

```
The model backing the 'PublicAreaContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

I am going crazy. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Compare [__MigrationHistory].Model cells between your dev and production mode with any comparison tool. If you see any changes that means the Dev model is not compatible with Production model. Why you do not set the Db initializer to null :: Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null); this will ignore the comparing between model and the database.

Comment: Try adding a source migration parameter. Use  -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase if you want everything scripted. http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2013/05/generate-sql-script-from-entity.html

Comment: Usually you get this error if you have done any changes to your model that are not yet migrated to the DB. Run `Add-Migration` once more and check if there is anything written to the `Up()` and `Down()` methods.

Comment: @FlorianHaider, I have done... `Up` and `Down` methods are generated empty...

@SteveGreene, I do not want everything scripted, just the differences

@BassamAlugili, If I do a compare they are different.. but the difference is for all rows, and before last change it worked... I am not sure to set the dbinitializer to null... if it give me the error must be a reason... but i dont know which

Comment: Ok, and did you make any changes to the generated script before running it on your production db?

Comment: no, I did not... I also deployed everything again! Perhaps the exe/dll deployed was not correct... so I deployed it again and run the script again... still does not work.. uff.. I really would like to delete the database and restart again but the database is full!